# I/O package in scala

Tags: scala

I have seen in many places in the scala code uses java.io package
    import java.io._

Is there no i/o package in scala, do we need java api for that.

And 1 more doubt, do we have a list anywhere where it is mentioned for this
we have to use java package as no scala package is available

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: The thing is since Scala can use Java packages, all the things that did not need to be changed were not recreated in Scala packages.

Comment: ok thanks Sarvesh, Is there any list of java packages we need to use as there is no comparative scala package available

Comment: Though scala has a `scala.io` package. it is provided very few things - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.io.package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backend of Scala is simply a Java VM. This means the interoperability of Java and Scala is very open, as you can call the operations and methods of one language into the other.
That being said, there is and will not be a Scala I/O package. This is a simple reinventing the wheel problem. The Java I/O package already exists and works, so there is no reason to make one in Scala as well.

Comment: Actually there is a `scala.io` package. It provides very little as of now. And its likely to stay like that. But you can never be sure that it will not diverge from the Java way and grow in future.